# javascript function not firing from gridview rowcommand?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to load jQuery dialog from code behind gridview rowcommand. Looks like javascript function is not firing from code behind.

### .vb file

```
Private Sub grdLoan_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdLoan.RowCommand
  If e.CommandName = "pdf" Then

    Dim message As String = "This is test message"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", True)
    'ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(grdLoan, Me.[GetType](), "MyScript", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", True)
   End If
End Sub
```

if I use `alert` in clientscript it is working fine. but JS function not working.

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Popup", "alert("This is test message"", True)
```

### html

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function ShowPopup(message) {
            alert(message);
                $(function () {
                    $("#dialog").html(message);
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                        buttons: {
                            Close: function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        },
                        modal: true
                    });
                });           
        };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it was not working, I made some modifications and now its working at my end. If you have a scriptmanager on your page, you can try this:

```
 string message = "This is test message";
                string jqueryCodeString = @"<script type='text/javascript'>ShowPopup('" + message + "');</script>";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Confirm1", jqueryCodeString, false);
```